# I’m trying to replace my doorknobs

Tags: doors, tools, screws, lock

Help! I am trying to replace my lock with a new lock that I bought at bunnings and I’m here with my screwdriver but look at this what kind of screwdriver do I need for this! What is this. I’m very confused. I tried poking it but it doesn’t come off. What can I use to remove the lock??

[image][image]

Comment: That’s a pop rivet not a screw.  You remove them with a drill, but first can you post a picture of the whole strike plate? I’ve never seen one riveted on.

Comment: Thank you I have updated the images is it easy enough to get off?

Comment: Is this a metal door? Why do you want to replace the existing lock? If it is not working smoothly, lubrication is the first resort.

Comment: That may not be a rivet, It may be removed by inserting an "allen wrench" or torks .

Comment: Is this in Australia? Someone here can probably help you, but to a certain extent door lock designs are country specific. Does the new lock from Bunnings have holes in exactly the same place as the existing one?

Answer (score 1):

Either the holes to secure the strike plate became very worn and the technician decided to "rivet" it into place or it might be a security addition. Drill those out using a small bit and keep increasing in size until the rivet falls out. You might find that the threads still exist so be careful and you might not have to use rivets to reinstall the strike plate.